# how to keep insert values from a istringstream to a vector?

Tags: c++

I want to take input from the user in a string and insert those values into a vector using stringstream 
my code looks like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    string s;
    getline(cin ,s);
    vector<int>vec;
    istringstream iss{s};
   while(iss){
        int temp;
        iss>>temp;
        vec.push_back(temp);
    }
    for (auto val:vec){
        cout << val<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am inserting 1 2 3 in the string but the output is 1 2 3 3 . this method is inserting the last 
element 2 times. 
but the following is working fine :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    string s;
    getline(cin ,s);
    vector<int>vec;
    istringstream iss{s};
    do{
        int temp;
        iss>>temp;
        vec.push_back(temp);
    }while(!iss.eof());
    
    for (auto val:vec){
        cout << val<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

can anyone tell why the first method is taking the last input twice?

Comment: On a side-note, if you learn about [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) you can simplify your code quite considerably: `std::vector<int> vec(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss), std::istream_iterator());` The first loop isn't needed. There's a corresponding [`std::ostream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) which can be used together with [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to omit the second loop also, but your explicit loop is more clear and understandable so keep it.

Comment: where is this method written there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's inserting twice because you don't check if extraction from the stream works. Do this instead:

```
int temp;
while(iss >> temp) {
    vec.push_back(temp);
}
```

You could use a `for` loop if you want to keep the scope of `temp` to a minimum:

```
for(int temp; iss >> temp;) {
    vec.push_back(temp);
}
```

Lets pretend that there is only *one* `int` in `iss` and walk through what happens in your loop:

```
while(iss) {              // 1.   4.   7.
    int temp;
    iss>>temp;            // 2.   5.
    vec.push_back(temp);  // 3.   6.
}
```

1. `iss` is in a good state, the condition is `true`.
2. Extracting an `int` into `temp` works.
3. The newly extracted `int` is stored.
4. `iss` is still in a good state, the condition is `true`.
5. Extracting an `int` into `temp` fails and sets `iss` in a failed state and leaves `temp` uninitialized
6. The previously extracted `int` is stored<sup>1</sup>
7. The condition is now `false`.

<sup>1</sup>Reading uninitialized values makes your program have *undefined behavior*. In this case it happens to give you the value stored in the `temp` from the previous loop - presumably because each `temp` created in the loop shares the same memory address.